# A question on Eigenvalues and Eigenvectors

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

[image]

Hey I need quite a bit of help, I know the question might seem easy, but I'm confused with the wording.

I know that the rule is $Av = \lambda(v)$.
Since there are two eigenvalues, I am assuming that $A$ is a 2x2 matrix. If these were actual numbers, I would be able to solve these quite easily, but having too much symbols and letters confuses me.

For the first question I think I can answer like this:
If $A$ is a square matrix, $v$ is a non-zero column vector with 
$Av=\lambda(v)$
for some scalar $\lambda$, then $v$ is an eigenvector of $A$ with eigenvalue $\lambda$.
Sorry if I'm confusing anyone, someone put me on the right track.
Help is very much appreciated :)

Comment: To me, it looks like the first question is looking for $A v_1 = \lambda_1 v_1$ and $A v_2 = \lambda_2 v_2$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

a) Sp3000 is correct, $Av_2=\lambda_2 v_2$ and $Av_1=\lambda_1v_1$ are the equations.

b) We take the transpose of both sides and have $(Av_2)^T=(\lambda_1 v_2)^T$

c) Since $\lambda_2$ is a scalar, we can say that $(\lambda_2 v_2)^T=\lambda_2 v_2^T$. So multiplying on the right, we have $v_2^TA^Tv_1=\lambda_2 v_2^T v_1$.

d) Since $A$ is symmetric we simplify the above to be $v_2^TAv_1=\lambda_2v_2^T v_1$. But we know $Av_1=\lambda_1 v_1$ so we can substitute $v_2^T(\lambda_1v_1)=\lambda_2v_2^Tv_1$. So subtracting, we have $\lambda_1v_2^Tv_1-\lambda_2v_2^Tv_1=0$ and $(\lambda_1-\lambda_2)v_2^Tv_1=0$. Since $\lambda_1\neq\lambda_2$ we must have that $v_2^Tv_1=0$.

e) I'm guessing that this is concerning an engineering course so I feel comfortable saying that $v_2^Tv_1=v_2\cdot v_1=0$ is the dot product and that the vectors are orthogonal.